# Adding a light to an existing switch

Tags: electrical

This may require a diagram, but as I’m doing this from my phone, that’s not doable at the moment.

I have an existing ceiling fixture in a bathroom that has 3 sets of wires going into it (no ground):

1. Black and white hot wire from fuse panel
2. Black and white wires out to a single pole light switch
3. Black and white wires out to a hallway light that has its own switch.

I need to add an existing fixture on the wall hopefully without tearing out a bunch of drywall. I ran a new set of wires from the ceiling fixture in the attic above, across to the wall and snaked it down to where I want the fixture installed. Easy enough.

My problem is that now I have 4 sets of wires and I really have no idea how they should all be connected to make this thing work. As you can probably gather, I’m not an electrician, but I have a basic understanding.

Comment: I take it the light switch box only has that one cable coming into it, with both the black and white wires attached to the switch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The black and white from the fuse panel is the constant power feeding two circuits: The bath light and the hall light. I take it the single pole light switch was used to control the old ceiling fixture. The two wires going to the hallway light need to be attached white to black from the fuse panel. That is one complete circuit.

**CEILING FIXTURE:** The two wires going to the light switch should both be considered "hot". Attach the switch black wire to the black wire from the fuse panel and the switch white wire to the black wire of your old ceiling fixture.  Attach the white wire of the old ceiling fixture to the fuse panel white wire. That's a complete circuit.

**NEW FIXTURE:** The switch can also be used to control the new fixture. Attach the black wire to the black wire on the old ceiling fixture. This will supply power to the new fixture when the switch is activated. Attach the white wire to the panel white wire.

In the end, the panel white wire will have three wires connected to it (all neutrals tied together). The fuse panel black wire will only have two wires connected to it because the switch will feed power to the ceiling and the new fixture at the same time.

[image]

Comment: It's worth noting two things: 1. This type of setup (*whats already existing), is not to code, and that 2. While it still will not be, it will not support future smart switches if thats in the outlook. Food for thought if you are looking at any remodeling or running of new wire now vs. never or later.

Comment: One thing that very much improves drawings like this is to bend the wires a bit so they cluster together to resemble the cables they must run in, and to make the junction points somewhat distinct.  A keystone rule of mains electrical is that currents must be equal and opposite /sum to zero in each cable or conduit.  It also helps to use typical  wire color and wire markings if required or helpful  (Hint: light green background allows white).

Comment: @noybman if the switch loop was installed before 2011 code, it is grandfathered and does not need to be replaced.  Newly run switch loops require /3 cable.

Comment: Thanks @Harper, did not know that. Makes me a bit happier that when I encounter these it's "ok" ... Nonetheless, finding it even in my own home annoyed me, so I fixed it and feel it's worth sharing so people are "fully armed" with the consideration of needing a neutral at a switch box.

Comment: Thanks Harper. I updated the diagram to be a bit more realistic. I'm not much of an artist.